# SARIMA mathematical expression

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, forecasting, arima, seasonality

In this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IK67f3IItfw at 4 min mark, Dr. Aric LaBarr shows an example of the following model: $ARIMA(1,0,1)(2,1,0)_{12}$ his resulting equation is: $W_{t}=c+\phi_{1}W_{t-1}+\phi_{2}W_{t-12}+\phi_{3}W_{t-24}+\theta_{1}\epsilon_{t-1}+\epsilon_{t}$

I tried to crossvalidate with my own polynomial expansion, I get the same equation but with the addition of the following 2 terms: $-\phi_{1}\phi_{2}W_{t-13}-\phi_{1}\phi_{3}W_{t-25}$.

I am a bit confused. I've seen in this forums other SARIMA polynomial results with higher order terms and multiplying the seasonal components resulting the mixed coefficients as part of the equation result.

Is there a property I am not aware of that eliminates these factors?

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: On a first glance Dr. LaBarr must be wrong.

Comment: Thank you, so I guess there must be terms with mixed coefficients that Dr. LaBarr didn't put...